# Your password may be compromised Chrome popup

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting, webflow

I just launched my website on firebase hosting. Design and login forms were created with webflow. Website built with nuxt js. For some reason, every time i try to login with login form, i get a popup from Chrome:

> Your password may be compromised - You just entered your password on a deceptive site....

What exactly is coursing this error ?

I have tried changing my password, i have tried simplifying the form by removing tags like name , id, data-name which is normally added to it via webflow. I dont know what else can be done and i clearly cannot launch with this type of problem. Any help is much appreciated.
[image]
website is https://waybetterrentals.com/login

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a programming error on your part.  Google have identified your site on their blacklist of 'phishing sites' you probably won't be able to do anything on your site to fix that. You can report the error to them here https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en-GB

Comment: How long does it normally take for them to check it out ?

Comment: If you go directly to the site it's not blocked by safe browsing so it might just be that the same password is being used on multiple sites. Chrome might think this might be a phishing attempt because it sees the same password being used elsewhere.

Comment: @abraham would that mean that i would be the only user seeing this error when trying to login and no other user would see this ?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: @SkyentGroup am also facing the same issue

Comment: facing the same issue